# ¿Porqué la función affected_rows de PHP no me devuelve la cantidad de registros en mi consulta SELECT realizada en MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, poo

Me encuentro haciendo una pequeña consulta preparada con la sentencia `SELECT` a mi BD en MySQL, y para validar si funciona estoy usando la función `affected_rows` con el estilo POO. Sucede que almaceno la cantidad de registros que devuelve la función `affected_rows` en una variable, la cual uso en un condicional `if` y dependiendo del resultado realiza una acción u otra.

Ahora cuando pruebo el código siempre me devuelve -1, y la verdad nose a que se deba este resultado, ya que he probado la misma consulta con POO pero sin prepararla y me muestra los registros encontrados sin problemas.

Asimimo quisiera aclarar que he leído el manual de PHP, y dice que la función `affected_rows` funciona de forma similar a la función `num_rows`, con la única diferencia que la primera se utiliza como método de la conexión mientras que la segunda se usa como método del resulset, quiere decir con la variable donde se almacena el array que devuelve la consulta. Soy nuevo en PHP y lo de consultas preparadas en nuevo para mí, espero puedan ayudarme.
Mi código es el siguiente:

Formulario de búsqueda HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>::Página Búsqueda::</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<form method="get" action="busqueda_alumno_querypreparada.php">
    <label>Ingrese nombre</label>
    <input type="text" name="busqueda">
    <input type="submit" name="buscar" value="Buscar!">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Código PHP

```
<?php
$conexion=new mysqli("localhost","root","","curso_php");

$busqueda=$_GET['busqueda'];

if ($conexion->connect_errno) {
    echo "Error de Conexión: ".$conexion->error;
}
$conexion->set_charset("utf8");

$consulta="SELECT DNI,APELLIDO,NOMBRES FROM ALUMNO WHERE NOMBRES=?";
$datos=$conexion->prepare($consulta);
$ok=$datos->bind_param('s',$busqueda);//Devuelve TRUE O FALSE el $ok es opcional para validación
$ok=$datos->execute();//Devuelve TRUE O FALSE

$registros=$conexion->affected_rows;

if ($registros>0) {
    //Aquí enlazamos cada campo que devuelve la consulta con un parametro en el mismo orden que lo creamos
    $ok=$datos->bind_result($dni,$apellido,$nombres);//Devuelve TRUE O FALSE
    while ($datos->fetch()) {
    echo "DNI: ".$dni."<br>";
    echo "Apellido: ".$apellido."<br>";
    echo "Nombre: ".$nombres."<br>"."<br>";
    }
    echo "Cantidad Registros: ".$registros;
}else{
    echo "Cantidad Registros: ".$registros."<br>";//Sirve para determinar si devuelve 0 ó -1=error
    echo "No se encontraron coincidencias!";
}
$datos->close();
$conexion->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ver... hay dos temas que explicar aquí.

## Primero

El uso de `affected_rows` sobre el objeto de conexión sólo te funcionaría si aplicaras

```
 $conexion->query('SELECT x FROM tabla');

 $filas = $conexion->affected_rows;
```

Cuando usas una sentencia preparada estás encapsulando la consulta en un objeto de tipo [mysqli statement](http://php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-stmt.php), y en él se delega lo que en otro caso preguntarías a la conexión misma.

lo lógico sería entonces usar

```
$datos = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
$datos->bind_param('s', $busqueda);
$datos->execute();

// le preguntas al statement y no a la conexión
$registros = $datos->affected_rows;
```

Porque ahora la cantidad de filas afectadas no las conoce la conexión sino el statement que encapsuló la consulta. **PEEERO** como dice **[la documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php)**, este método sólo representa las filas afectadas en sentencias DELETE, INSERT y UPDATE. Esto nos lleva al siguiente tema:

## Segundo

Para lo que necesitas, en realidad tienes que usar el método **[num_rows](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php)** y además con una operación adicional, que es **[store_result](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php)** (porque de otra manera el statement es un cursor que no sabe *ni quiere saber* de antemano cuántas filas va a recorrer). Lo que nos queda entonces es:

```
$datos = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
$datos->bind_param('s', $busqueda);
$datos->execute();
$datos->store_result(); // paso extra

// FINALMENTE!!! 
$registros = $datos->num_rows;
```

Si todo esto no te funcionara, siempre puedes debuggear escribiendo por pantalla el error:

```
echo 'Algo malo pasó: '. $datos->error;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta tan detallada me sirvió a la perfección. Aunque me queda la duda si usara: $conexion->affected_rows junto con el store_result() sería incorrecto? porque lo he probado y funciona sin problemas.

Comment: A lo mejor funciona igual. Lo malo de cosas que funcionan y no están documentadas es que en alguna versión posterior lo quitan y no le avisan a nadie, porque era como un easter egg